# Relationship between two triangle side lengths where one other side is shared

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This question was asked on an Australian year 10 (15 to 16 year olds) practice exam.
Diagram of two triangles with sides a and b indicated:

[image: Diagram]

"Determine the relationship between the values of $a$ and $b$ by writing $a$ in terms of $b$". The solution given was simply the following.

$a=\dfrac{b}{b \sqrt 3 - 1} \tag{1}\label{1}$

My attempt to solve this used the cosine rule on each of the two smaller triangles to get the side length opposite the $30°$ angle, then on the larger triangle for the side length opposite the $60°$ angle, giving the following relationship between a and b.

$\left(\sqrt{a^2 + 1 - a \sqrt 3} + \sqrt{b^2 + 1 - b \sqrt 3}\right)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - ab \tag{2}\label{2}$

However I was not able to simplify (\ref{2}) to get equation (\ref{1}).

My question is:

1. How can equation (\ref{2}) be simplified to give equation (\ref{1}) using algebra that is accessible to a high school student?
2. Is there another way, perhaps using other trigonometric identities, that does not use the form of (\ref{2})?

Comment: Adding triangle areas rather than side lengths makes this much simpler.

Comment: To support aschepler's comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1294749/947379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As suggested by aschepler,

sum of areas of the 2 smaller triangles = area of the larger triangle.

$$\frac{1}{2}(a)(1)\sin 30^o+\frac{1}{2}(1)(b)\sin 30^o=\frac{1}{2}(a)(b)\sin 60^o$$

$$\frac{1}{2}(a)(1)\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)+\frac{1}{2}(1)(b)\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)=\frac{1}{2}(a)(b)\left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right)$$

$$a+b=ab\sqrt 3$$

$$\therefore  a=\frac{b}{b \sqrt 3-1}$$

Comment: This is most likely what the examiner intended. Thanks to aschepler's suggestion and Li Kwok Keung's step by step answer.

Answer (score 2):

[image: ab1]

The answer to your $2^\text{nd}$ question is “Yes”. But, to express $a$ in terms of $b$, you need to add two lines to your diagram and extend an existing segment. First, construct the perpendicular to the side $CA$ through the vertex $C$ to cut the extended side $AB$ at $P$. Then, draw a parallel line $CQ$ to $CP$ through the point $D$ to meet the extended side $AB$ at $Q$.

As shown in the diagram, the segment $CP$ makes $\triangle APC$ a right-angled-triangle, while segment $DQ$ makes $\triangle AQD$ an isosceles triangle.

Using the properties of a right-angled-triangle, we shall write, $\space AP=\dfrac{AC}{\cos\left(60^o\right)}=2b$.

Therefore, we have, $BP=AP-AB=2b-a$.

Since $AD$ is the $\hat{A}$-angle-bisector, we can apply angle bisector theorem to $\triangle ABC$ to obtain,
$$\dfrac{DB}{DC}=\dfrac{AB}{AC}=\dfrac{a}{b}$$

Now, consider the triangle $BPC$, where $DQ$ is parallel to its side $CP$. Therefore, we have,
$$\dfrac{BQ}{QP}=\dfrac{DB}{DC}=\dfrac{a}{b},$$
with which we deduce that,
$$\dfrac{BQ}{BP}=\dfrac{BQ}{BQ+QP}=\dfrac{a}{a+b}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad BQ=\dfrac{a}{a+b}BP=\left(\dfrac{a}{a+b}\right)\left(2b-a\right).\tag{2}$$

According to the properties of an isosceles triangle, we know that, in $\triangle AQD$,
$$AQ= 2AD\cos\left(30^o\right)=\sqrt{3}.\tag{3}$$

Using (2), $AQ$ can be expressed also as,
$$AQ=AB+BQ=a+\left(\dfrac{a}{a+b}\right)\left(2b-a\right).\tag{4}$$

When we equate (3) and (4), we get the equation needed for determining $a$ in terms of $b$.
$$a+\left(\dfrac{a}{a+b}\right)\left(2b-a\right)=\sqrt{3}.$$

Answer (score -1):

I would like to further add that this problem can be solved fairly simply using the method below:

[image]

1.) First, we label the triangle $\triangle ABC$ with a point $D$ that lies on $AC$ for our ease. We can also labor $\angle ACB=\alpha$. Now, we draw a line $DE$ from $D$ onto a point $E$ that lies on $AB$, such that $DE\parallel BC$.

2.) This gives us an isosceles triangle $\triangle BED$ where $\angle EDB=\angle EBD=30^\circ$. We also know that $BE=ED$ as well, furthermore, we can calculate the length of $BE$ and/or $ED$ as we know the length of $BD$, there are multiple ways of doing this (law of cosines, dropping a perpendicular, etc...), but it's fairly trivial so I'll just use the result and say that $BE=ED=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$. This also implies that the remaining line segment $EA=b-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ or $\frac{b\sqrt3 -1}{\sqrt3}$.

3.) With this information now, we can finish off the problem. Notice that $\triangle AED$ is similar to $\triangle ABC$ via the AAA property. In that case, we can use the Thales theorem and say that:

$$\frac{1}{a\sqrt3}=\frac{b\sqrt3 -1}{b\sqrt3}$$

$$\frac{1}{a}=\frac{b\sqrt3 -1}{b}$$

Now we can just "flip" the expressions and get the desired result:

$$a=\frac{b}{b\sqrt3 -1}$$

To answer your "first" question, it may be possible to simplify that algebraic expression and find an equation for $b$ in terms of $a$, but as you stated too, this is not something that would typically be expected of a high-schooler. Even if you can simplify it, its simply not an efficient way to solve the problem.